# Using .load() to Sequentially Load a Series of HTML Documents

Tags: ajax, jquery

**BACKGROUND**: I'm trying to use .load() to build a site from several
pages, where a user can click a button to load the next page's
content using .load().

**PROBLEM**: The .load() only works on the first click (loads
content from pagetwo.html), then doesn't load any
content for pages after that.

**CODE**:
My start page markup looks like this:

```
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
<p>This is page 1.</p>
<button id="pageone">next</button>

</div>
</body>
```

Then my pages 2-5 contain only partial HTML, to be loaded
into div.content:

Page 2:

```
<p>This is page 2.</p>
<button id="pagetwo">next</button>
```

Page 3:

```
<p>This is page 3.</p>
<button id="pagethree">next</button>
```

Etc.

My jQuery `script.js` is loaded only once, with the full start page html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//load pages
$('button#pageone').click(function () {
$("div.content").load("page-two.html");
});
$('button#pagetwo').click(function () {
$("div.content").load("page-three.html");
});
$('button#pagethree').click(function () {
$("div.content").load("page-four.html");
});

});
```

Any ideas on why only the first .load() request works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID `#pagetwo` and on onwards are newly introduced elements to the DOM after the first initial `$(document).ready()`. Thus, you'd have to access it differently there after:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#pageone', function() {
   $("div.content").load("page-two.html");
});

$(document).on('click', 'button#pagetwo', function() {
   $("div.content").load("page-three.html");
});

$(document).on('click', 'button#pagethree', function() {
   $("div.content").load("page-four.html");
});
```

The `.on()` handler will listen to any new elements through the entire document (As it starts at root) at any one stage. Your initial code was looking for elements that were present on *just* page load.

To read more about it, See the documentation about the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler regarding new elements at "*Direct and delegated events*".

Comment: Thanks @MackieeE - problem solved! So does the .on() always catch new elements even when it's inside $(document).ready()?

Comment: @Marcatectura No problem dude =) and no, it's all about the `$(selector)` and event bubbling, if it was `$('#somediv').on('click')`, and the `<div id="somediv">` wasn't in the DOM at the point of load, the `click` would never run, because it's not listening for `$('#somediv')` as it didn't *exist*. If you instead look for `$(document)`, it'll transverse down the DOM tree to find `<div id="somediv">`.. I hope that made sense!

Comment: @Marcatectura If you need me to clarify anything, feel free to ask =)